# CKEditor in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, ckeditor

In using CKEditor latest version available now. In Chrome and Firefox it is working without any issues. But in IE7 I am facing some display issues.

When I click Image button the background goes black
body p in the bottom is not looking same as shown in Chrome
Also I get JavaScript error undefined is null or not an object

Please help

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your page isn't running in Quirks mode (that the source is correct)? I don't see this issues e.g. on http://ckeditor.com/demo.

CKEditor 4.0 doesn't have support for Quirks mode - we're working on it right now.

Comment: Fixed it. The issue is due to doctype. It worked after changing the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>